# How can I implement `hashValue` using an object's memory location?

Tags: swift, swift3

I would like to have a `Dictionary` whose key type is a class type. Dictionaries require their keys to be `Hashable`.

In my case, the instances of that class type compare equal if they are reference-equal (they share their memory location). Is there a way that I can implement the `Hashable` protocol's `hashValue` based on the object's memory address?

In Swift 2, this could be done by using `Unmanaged.toOpaque`, however that method is gone in the first Swift 3 preview.

Comment: `Unmanaged.toOpaque()` would be `OpaquePointer(bitPattern: Unmanaged.passUnretained(self))` in Swift 3, but `unsafeAddress(of: self)`  is simpler.

Comment: Thank you. The other question didn't come up when I Googled it ("reference" and "key" being pretty generic search terms).